# Using Mod_wsgi with Anaconda python library

Tags: python, apache, flask, anaconda, mod-wsgi

I have install mod_wsgi --with-python option.
When i am running flask app on apache it is saying "No module name flask"
Flask is already installed in anaconda.
How can i force mod_wsgi to pick up the anaconda libraries.

Comment: Is their a system Python version, the same version as Anaconda version? Eg. if Anaconda Python is 2.7, is there a normal system Python of version 2.7. What do you get for ``import sys; sys.prefix`` in the Anaconda Python version? Is Flask installed in a virtual environment created for Anaconda Python, or the main Anaconda installation?

Comment: sys.prefix display "/home/jdnco/anaconda2".Yes there is a system python version 2.7 and right now mod_wsgi using that i want mod_wsgi use anaconda python.

Comment: I have added this WSGIPythonHome /home/jdnco/anaconda2 in httpd.conf it display error "No module site" and if i remove this path it shows "No module name flask".by doing ldd /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so it showing linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff219fa000)
 libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007fb7115ba000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb71139e000)

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to do the following.

When you are building mod_wsgi from source code, set the `LD_RUN_PATH` environment variable to `/home/jdnco/anaconda2/lib`. Thus go back and do something like the following in mod_wsgi source code:

```
make distclean
./configure --with-python=/home/jdnco/anaconda2/bin/python
LD_RUN_PATH=/home/jdnco/anaconda2/lib make
sudo make install
```

This will ensure it is linking with the correct library. Check with `ldd` again.

Then in the Apache configuration file also set:

```
WSGIPythonHome /home/jdnco/anaconda2
```

Both of these is necessary when using a Python installation in a non standard location which matches version in system directories.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Ok i have done the above steps, now doing ldd it is showing /home/user/anaconda2 path.So till now everything is good but now when i access the application it showing "No module name site" error.Any comments on this?

Comment: Do you mean ``ldd`` is showing it finding ``libpython2.7.so`` in ``/home/jdnco/anaconda2/lib``? What version of Anaconda Python is this? Anaconda Python has caused all sorts of problems over the years. There was yet another fix related to it in mod_wsgi not long back, so make sure you are using most recent mod_wsgi source code.

Comment: ldd /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc0592b000)
 libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /home/jdnco/anaconda2/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f008443f000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0084211000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f008400d000)
 libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f0083e0a000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0083b07000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0083745000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0084a73000)

Comment: python
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import sys
>>> sys.prefix
'/home/jdnco/anaconda2'
Mod_wsgi version -- mod-4.5.7. When i don't set WSGIPythonHome in httpd.conf it says "No module name flask" but flask is already installed in anaconda and when i put WSGIPythonHome it says "No module name site"

Comment: Is this anything related to permission for /home/user/anaconda2 but no permission related error is displaying?

Comment: Ignore the current Apache/mod_wsgi for now. Go and try and install mod_wsgi-express as outlined in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi See if it fails when you run mod_wsgi-express after it is installed into your Anaconda Python installation.

Comment: ok.i am trying its saying "Cannot run apache as root user".Do you have any gmail id?

Comment: Ok when i run it from different user it is running.I go to the localhost:8000 page and it is showingsnake image.But how can i know that it is installed in anaconda python or system python . I just run the python setup.py command without specifying any python path so where it goes?

Comment: **Updated**...I run my .wsgi file using "mod_wsgi-express .wsgi start server" and my flask runs on url "localhost:8000" but i want to run it on apache server.i stop apache service it stills running.So what i have to do now.I want my both drupal and python-application to be run on apache server

Comment: The fact that mod_wsgi-express works shows your main Apache should also be able to work, since all mod_wsgi-express is doing is starting Apache but with a generated config and the mod_wsgi.so that pip install of mod_wsgi created. Time to sleep now.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Its just i want to start wsgi application when i start apache.I have read your post somewhere i can also setup server in mod-wsgi express and then starting and stopping apache will on/off the application.Thanks for your support.I will try to figure this out