# Django 1.10 SSLv2_method import error when send_mail behind an Apache2.4

Tags: django, apache, ssl, mod-wsgi, tls1.2

I'm trying to install a nearly empty django 1.10 project behind an Apache2 mod_wsgi. In the project settings, I use EMAIL_USE_TLS = True, EMAIL_PORT='587' to send an email via gmail from a web form. I can send the email just fine when I do manage.py runserver standalone at console. But when the django project sits behind Apache2, I'm always getting this error:

```
/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_method
```

Django 1.10 runs on a Ubuntu 16.04 with python2.7 in a conda virtual environment. The Apache2 serves a few https sites just fine. I understand SSLv2 has largely been deprecated by modern systems and it's disabled on my system's openssl. The mod_ssl.conf has the default config (enable all except SSLv3 disabled). Why would this SSLv2_method be a dependency anyways?

Notes on my current workaround: since I have a local postfix that relays to gmail on this server, in settings, I just changed EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost' without SSL or TLS and sans-authentication but the end result is the same: django behind mod_wsgi shows the same error. I ended up writing a crude _sendmail helper that uses smtplib for the form mail viewer to send through postfix, and that worked. Of course I would want to revert to the standard django send_mail. So please advise in any way you can.

Following is the traceback from Django:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: https://wr2opt/contact/

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'home',
 'contact',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'crispy_forms']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/wr200m/workspace/wr200m/optionswww/src/contact/views.py" in contact
  20.         send_mail(subject, message, emailFrom, emailTo, fail_silently=False)

File "/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py" in send_mail
  56.         fail_silently=fail_silently,

File "/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py" in get_connection
  36.     klass = import_string(backend or settings.EMAIL_BACKEND)

File "/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py" in import_string
  20.     module = import_module(module_path)

File "/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)

File "/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in <module>
  3. import ssl

File "/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/ssl.py" in <module>
  97. import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate

Exception Type: ImportError at /contact/
Exception Value: /home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_method
```

This is the Django exception - note that this is after I built the mod_wsgi.so from source and installed to apache2, having specified LD_RUN_PATH and the anaconda python. You can see the sys.executable points to /usr/bin/python (which also runs the same version 2.7.12), whereas previously with the stock mod_wsgi.so it actually pointed to the anaconda python. I did specify WSGIPythonHome in apache2 mod_wsgi.conf to anaconda python with the newly built mod_wsgi.so

```
ImportError at /contact/
/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_method
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://wr2opt/contact/
Django Version: 1.10.5
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_method
Exception Location: /home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/ssl.py in <module>, line 97
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
['/home/wr200m/workspace/wr200m/optionswww/src',
 '/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python27.zip',
 '/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.4.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/wr200m/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg']
Server time:    Fri, 3 Mar 2017 14:22:18 +0000
```

This is all the lib subdirs in anaconda that contained a form of *ssl.so and I also added them to os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] in the project wsgi.py before anything else (with ~ expanded)

```
~/anaconda2/envs/pgadmin4/lib
~/anaconda2/envs/pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
~/anaconda2/envs/pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
~/anaconda2/lib
~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
~/anaconda2/pkgs/cryptography-1.5-py27_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
~/anaconda2/pkgs/openssl-1.0.2k-0/lib
~/anaconda2/pkgs/openssl-1.0.2k-0/lib/engines
~/anaconda2/pkgs/python-2.7.13-0/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
```

Comment: Was mod_wsgi compiled for Anaconda Python? You can't just try and force mod_wsgi to use a Python virtual environment built by Anaconda if mod_wsgi was compiled for a different Python distribution. That said, this may come down to being caused by Anaconda being a bit dependent in some cases on ``LD_LIBRARY_PATH`` being set.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40151469/using-mod-wsgi-with-anaconda-python-library to build from the source with anaconda2's python as well as your other instruction at https://anaconda.org/pypi/mod_wsgi using pip install within anaconda2. I was able to use mod_wsgi-express start-server without any issue (email got sent). But after I installed the mod_wsgi.so either built from source or with pip, the problem is even stranger after bouncing apache2.

Comment: ldd shows the newly built mod_wsgi.so has my anaconda2/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 but the python executable on django now shows /usr/bin/python instead of the previous anaconda2/bin/python, all the while the original problem remains. THe stock mod_wsgi.so was linked to libpython2.7.so.1.0 that came from the distro. What do you recommend me to do with LD_LIBRARY_PATH? I'm not quite following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690980/how-to-set-ld-library-path-for-apachewsgi-website

Comment: What do you mean by 'the python executable on django '? If you are looking at value of ``sys.executeble`` inside of runing Django application, it doesn't matter what it is as mod_wsgi isn't executing ``python`` executable by loading the library, so that is all that is important.

Comment: Find the lib directory in Anaconda distribution which has the Anaconda version of the SSL libraries in it. What is it? Try at very start of WSGI script file before anything else, importing ``os`` and set ``os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']`` to that directory.

Comment: Yes Graham, sys.executable is what I was looking at. A bit desperate, I looked for all uniq dirname inside /home/wr200m/anaconda2 that contains .so files that look like *ssl*, that returned a variety of lib subdirectories, which I in turn set in the project wsgi.py right after import os and before anything else. I still have the same import error. At the risk of sounding silly, would you like to see the result of   `for f in 'find /home/wr200m/anaconda2/ -name "*.so"|grep ssl'; do dirname $f; done | sort | uniq`

Comment: It is going to be the ``openssl-1.0.2k-0`` or ``openssl-1.0.2k-0/engines`` directories. The problem is that Apache may have pulled in a SSL library of same name which is older and so supersedes the Anaconda one. There isn't any way around that except maybe not load mod_ssl in Apache, which may not be practical if need to run HTTPS for site.

Comment: Ok. I tried to use just one of these two to no avail.. So in the end, I took a short cut. I extended the django.core.mail.backends.base.EmailBackend for this django project, so my customized version just connects to the local postfix SMTP, without getting bogged down at 'import ssl'  Nonetheless, thanks so much for your help. It's been very enlightening!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also met with this issue when hosting a conda environment with Apache2. My Apache2 was installed with **apt-get**. There are actually two openssl installed in my system.

1. /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
2. /home/vamei/anaconda3/lib/libssl.so

One belongs to system, and the other belongs to conda. If you use Apache to host the site, Apache will use system's openssl, which is not expected by conda. I added the following line to /etc/apache2/envvars to solve the problem:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/vamei/anaconda3/lib
```

Note: I also tried other methods as suggested in various posts, but they all failed:

1. use os.environ in Python to add LD_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_RUN_PATH
2. use mod_env to add system environment LD_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_RUN_PATH

Comment: That then means that Apache will use the wrong one though and so mod_ssl could well break.

Comment: In my case, Apache is working properly. I agree that it is not a good idea to import the variable in the whole scope of Apache, but I have found no other solutions. Maybe someone can suggest a way to import only in WSGI.

Comment: You can't, because mod_wsgi is using a process inherited from Apache, it is not an exec of a separate program where you have the opportunity to bring in different shared libraries. The only safe solution would be to use mod_wsgi-express behing Apache or nginx acting as a proxy.

Comment: Thank you! I decided to do this now and mod_ssl is still working. So in all, I have my anaconda python built mod_wsgi installed with apache2, and pointed the LD_LIBRARY_PATH of apache2 to using the openssl in the same anaconda env as opposed to the system version. This works now! Sidenote: Was still seeing a problem reported [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608236/eclipse-and-google-app-engine-importerror-no-module-named-sysconfigdata-nd-u), and the solution is a workaround for a ubuntu issue from 2013!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real solution but I hope if anyone else encounter a similar issue, I can demonstrate a work-around.

As can be seen from the discussion under my question, my problem seems to be with the Apache2 loading an older ssl lib, before the anaconda-python compliant mod_wsgi can pull in the correct .so. Since this Apache2 also serves other sites over https, and I don't have the expertise nor time to further tinker for a real solution, I have opted for the following:

- On the local system, use a postfix that relays to an external SMTP server (https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/postfix-smtp-debian7)
- Then within django, customize an EmailBackend (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/email/) that connects to the local postfix. Thus the need to import ssl is done away with.